# My php link works but when I use file_exists it won't connect

Tags: php, file-exists

```
$rest = substr(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['autodate'])), 6, 4);

$filename = "G://Corporate Operations/Transportation Maintenance/Road Service/{$rest} road service invoice scans/{$row['invoice']}.pdf";
if (file_exists($filename))
    {echo FALSE;}
else 
    {echo TRUE;}
```

UPDATED CODE

```
$rest = substr(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['autodate'])), 6, 4);

$filename = "G://Corporate Operations/Transportation Maintenance/Road Service/{$rest} road service invoice scans/{$row['invoice']}.pdf";
if (file_exists($filename))
    {echo "True";}
else 
    {echo "False";}
```

The true and false are switched to be in the correct spots for the function return.

Updated Question******

I am adding another aspect. I think the issue is the php does not have the permission to access the folder to read it. Any idea on how to extend the permissions? To add my log in into the code to see it?

Comment: by the way, make it easy - `$rest = date("Y", strtotime($row['autodate']);`

Comment: swap your false and true, and if you ever `echo false;` you wont see anything

Comment: Change your file path. Replace the space with %20 or setup a test path without spaces in the name to see if that causes the problem.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I have a thought that the issue is connecting to the G:// at all. Because it won't say the file is found if that is the only thing there. But I tried Javascript and other things too and it won't connect.

Comment: `for the function return` the code in the question doesn't return anything. `echo somethingornothing;` is not a return statement.

Comment: Oh yes. I know. I just keep wording it incorrectly. My apologies.

Comment: Did you print out the filepath to physically see if it renders alright? ie `print_r($filename);`

Comment: Yep. Tried that and I copied and pasted it and it worked. But it still is not working.

Comment: can you confirm? `file_exists($filename)` still doesn ot work? but `print_r($filename)` does work? I have simmilar issue. I can get it to work the the directory `file_exists("/data/")` but not for the filename `file_exists("/data/file.csv")`.  Not sure it is a rigths issues as the file has these rights `-rw-rw-r-- `

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got your false and true mixed up to me...

```
if (file_exists(str_replace('/', '\\', $filename))) {
    echo "File exists";
} else {
    echo "File not found";
}
```

Also.. echoing `false` will never show you anything so I'd recommend not doing that and instead use a clear message.

I've added str_replace to swap out forward slashes for backslashes on windows

Comment: So I did that, and it still is not finding the file. I just put the echos to give me some feedback because it is not returning anything.

Comment: Thank you. It appears it does not want to work still. The file is always not found. I know the file exists. I have checked and I have checked this link.

Answer (score 0):

To get a local file you have to use file:/// and do not put two slashes after drive letter, so in your case in `<a href="">` it would be:

```
file:///G:/Corporate Operations/Transportation Maintenance/Road Service/{$rest} road service invoice scans/{$row['invoice']}.pdf
```

Also you might find it handy to use [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: I did try this and the real path as well and neither seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

got this to work for me

```
$thumb_name = "/home/path/to/file/data/file.csv";

if(file_exists($thumb_name)) {
    //some_code
    echo "<br>tnumb_name exists: $thumb_name <br>";
}
```

this helped me. do a `ls /` on your server and work from there for the path